# Calculating the limit of a function of itself

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to show that the limit of $f(x)=xe^{-2f(x)}$ at infinity is equal to $+\infty$.
From the previous questions, I know that :

- $f$ is $C^1$ and strictly increasing on $[0,+\infty[$ and $f'(0)=1$
- $f(x) \geq 0$
- $f(x) \leq x$

I have no idea how to proceed, but I tried using the formal definition and got a result I'm quite sure is wrong and that I shouldn't be using this :

[image]

Feels circular or I don't know ..

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean $g(x)=xe^{-2f(x)}$? The definition otherwise seems silly

Comment: no it's not, and yeah it was a despair call

Comment: Since $f$ is strictly increasing, you know that the limit in question either exists or it's infinite. See if you can get a contradiction by assuming that it's finite and taking the limit on both sides of the functional equation

Comment: Just for  your curiosity, have a look at Lambert function. In your case $f(x))=\frac 12 W(2x)$

Answer (score 1):

Let's put $y=f(x) $ so that $x=ye^{2y}$ and thus $x, y$ are of same sign. Since we are considering $x\geq 0$ it follows that $y\geq 0$ and clearly $x$ is a strictly increasing continuous function of $y$. Moreover $x\to\infty $ as $y\to\infty$. And hence by inverse function theorem $y=f(x) $ is a stricting increasing continuous function of $x$ and tends to $\infty $ as $x\to\infty $. There is no need to use derivatives here.

Comment: I think I'm not to use that since the very next question is asking to show that $f(x)$ is bijective.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can answer questions with details I'm supposed to achieve later on.

Comment: @archaic: I don't see how to avoid it. The fact that a function is strictly increasing automatically makes it (and its inverse) a bijection.

Comment: Of course, but as I said, I think it wouldn't b a valid answer since the question on bijection is in the next question.

Comment: Much thanks anyhow!

Comment: @archaic: I don't think so. If your professor insists that this is an invalid answer then sorry to say you have tough luck.

Comment: @egreg: Because $\lim_{x\to\infty} f^{-1}(x)=\infty$ where $f^{-1}(x)=xe^{2x}$. It's just a matter of inverting coordinate axes.